# Function in R to convert a 0-1 number to hexidecimal color code, trouble with missing "green"

Tags: r, function, colors

I am attempting to create a function that converts a number between 0 and 100 into a hexidecimal colour that can be used for later plotting. The data are for a range of freshwater health scores of the form:

ID.........Indicator.........Short.............Score

1..........Water quality....WQual..............81

2..........Basin Condition..BC.................85

3..........Water quantity...WQuan...........66

4..........Biodiversity.....Bio............ ........43

To manipulate the data I am using the packages `plyr`, `colorRamp` and `data.frame`.

The function below:

```
FHI_col<-function(x, Col_ramp, Indicator_colours){
  ##first I need to convert each score to fit the colorRamp
  FHI_scores_1<-plyr::ddply(x,.(Score), transform,
                            Score_1 = 1-(Score/100))
  ##define the colorscheme using the colorRamp package
  Col_ramp<-colorRamp(matlab.like2(800))

  ##convert the scores into red, green and blue
  Indicator_colours<-Col_ramp(FHI_scores_1$Score_1)

  ## convert red, green, blue colors into hexidecimal format and add to dataframe
  ## this is where it goes wrong! 
  FHI_scores_2<-plyr::ddply(FHI_scores_1,.(), transform,
                            Score_cols=rgb(.(Indicator_colours), maxColorValue=256))

  ##additional tidying up for export
  FHI_scores_3 <- as.data.table(FHI_scores_2)
  FHI_scores_4 <-FHI_scores_3[Score==0, Score_cols := "grey60"]
  FHI_scores_5 <- FHI_scores_4[order(ID),]
  return(FHI_scores_5)
}
```

When I run the function on the dataset of the type provided I get the error message

```
Error in rgb(.(Indicator_colours: 
  argument "green" is missing, with no default
```

If I run the same code as individual commands then I get the desired output. However trying to tie them together in function leads to this error. If `Indicator_colours` sits outside the function then it works!

I have tried various variations on the offending line such as:

```
FHI_scores_2<-plyr::ddply(FHI_scores_1,.(), transform,
                         Score_cols=rgb(.(Indicator_colours[,1], Indicator_colours[,2],
                       Indicator_colours[,3]), maxColorValue=256))
```

in an attempt to directly call each red, green and blue column, But it gives the same result, as does trying to convert Indicator_colours into a data.table and using the `$` operator.

Any assistance on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated, no doubt I am missing something quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with and a solution.
First I moved the definition of the colour scheme outside of the function

```
Col_ramp<-colorRamp(matlab.like2(800))
```

Then I appended the red, green and blue colour output to the original dataframe and calculated the hexadecimal from there.

```
 FHI_col<-function(x){
  FHI_scores_1<-plyr::ddply(x,.(Score), transform,
                    Score_1 = 1-(Score/100))
  FHI_scores_2<-ddply(FHI_scores_1,.(Score_1), transform,
            Score_cols=Col_ramp(Score_1))

  FHI_scores_3<-ddply(FHI_scores_2,.(Score_cols.1, Score_cols.2, Score_cols.3), transform,
            Score_colour=rgb(Score_cols.1, Score_cols.2, Score_cols.3, maxColorValue=256))

  FHI_scores_4 <- as.data.table(FHI_scores_3)
  FHI_scores_5 <-FHI_scores_4[Score==0, Score_colour := "grey60"]
  FHI_scores_6 <- FHI_scores_5[order(ID),]
  return(FHI_scores_6)
}
```

If anyone can contribute a more elegant solution I would be grateful.